# How to detect user idleness in JavaFX 2?

Tags: javafx-2

I have JavaFX application, and I want to detect that some amount of time passed since last action (mouse click, button press, etc.). Is there a way to register some global action listener, or do I need to listen for actions on all my controls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems I found the solution - registering event filter on Stage (scalafx syntax):

```
stage.delegate.addEventFilter[javafx.event.Event](
  javafx.event.EventType.ROOT,
  new javafx.event.EventHandler[javafx.event.Event] {
    def handle(e: javafx.event.Event) = {
      StageDirector ! "event"
    }
  }
)
```